# Flash not play, when add to form C#

Tags: c#, flash

When i code:

```
form_show(){
    myFlash = new Flash()
    this.Controls.Add(myFlash);
    myFlash.Load(0, url);
    myFlash.Play();
}
```

My flash play pretty.
But i code:

```
form_show(){
    myFlash = new Flash();
    myFlash.Load(0, url);
    myFlash.Play();
   this.Controls.Add(myFlash);
}
```

my flash not play.

Plz, Who tell my why.

---

Time of  myFlash.Load(0, url); is so slow.
Just i want to do it in background Thread. And then play on my form

```
Flash myFlash = new Flash();
Thread th;
form_load(){
   th = new Thread(myFlash.Load());
   th.Start();
}
form_show(){
    th.join(); 
   this.Controls.Add(myFlash);
   myFlash.Play();
}
```

But myFlash not play

Comment: If you have a solution whats the problem?

Answer (score 3):

In your failure example you have told the flash to play before it has been added as a control.